# String and Suffix Matching from a Suffix List

Tags: string-matching

I'm having trouble finding an algorithm that matches (or fails to match) a substring of a string to a suffix from a list of suffixes. The hits I'm finding are for suffix trees and suffix arrays, but they are not quite what I am looking for.

My particular problem is a fully qualified hostname - possibly malformed - and trying to match the suffix provided by the [banned suffix list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) published by Mozilla. As a concrete example, given `w.x.y.z.example.com`, I need to identify it as hostname `w`, domain `example.com`, and know that `example.com` is valid domain.

As a degenerative example, I may need to take `example.com` and know that its a domain with no host, and that matching it to `*.com` would be wrong. And the negative cases only get worse when you factor in suffixes like `pvt.k12.ma.us`, `nasushiobara.tochigi.jp`, `公司.cn` and `السعودیة`.

The eventual application will be DNS hostname matching in X509 certificates. Hence the reason there may be malformed input from miscreants.

I think this algorithm should run in *m log n*. *log n* for each lookup into the [sorted] list of suffixes, and *m* for each DNS label.

I think it may be a case of not seeing the forest through the trees. Does anyone know of an efficient algorithm for matching substrings from a list of suffixes?